# Having an error at build time showing cannot read property 'getStart ' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

> ionic-app-script task: "build"
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStart' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStart' of undefined

Tried Changing the JsxAttribute interface (removed all code from inside it), not working, tried updating and downgrading tslint and typescript, also not working.

This is my `Package.json`

```
 {
  "name": "TransporterUI",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "angular": "^1.7.6",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "cordova": "^8.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-permission": "^0.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-ext": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "2.6.0",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "4.0.10",
    "ionic": "^4.8.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-app-lib": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "latest": "^0.2.0",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "npm": "^6.6.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "v1": "^1.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
```

StackTrace:

> [10:49:03]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
>       [10:49:03]  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStart' of undefined
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStart' of undefined
>           at Object.replaceNode (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientUI\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\typescript-utils.js:34:27)
>           at Object.getUpdatedAppNgModuleContentWithDeepLinkConfig (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientUI\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\deep-linking\util.js:267:31)
>           at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientUI\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:139:39
>           at new Promise ()
>           at transpileWorker (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientUI\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:107:12)
>           at Object.transpile (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientUI\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\transpile.js:64:12)
>           at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ClientUI\node_modules@ionic\app-scripts\dist\build.js:109:82
>           at 
>       [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.

Vulnerabilty errors:
npm WARN @angular/animations@7.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/common@7.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/forms@7.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@7.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@7.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@7.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@7.2.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@7.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@7.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@7.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@7.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic/angular@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@^7.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic/angular@4.0.0 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@^7.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0||^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.2.3 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 67 packages from 26 contributors and updated 1 package in 33.915s
fixed 2 of 136 vulnerabilities in 26104 scanned packages
  134 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated

Comment: what is `getStart`? if it is a variable/property then make it `public`

Comment: your `package.json` is pointless here, give us some code

Comment: maybe it is internal property of Typescript.d.ts, i have not defined any varibale/method named same.

Comment: Add full stack trace error.

Comment: edited and added stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have dependency mismatch with the package versions, to fix it you need to install the matched versions or latest versions of the packages.

To easily do that, you can use [npm check updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

Run :

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates       # Install the package first
ncu                              # shows all the upgradable packages
ncu -u                           # To upgrade
npm install                      # update installed packages and package-lock.json
```

and also try to delete `package-lock.json` first to fresh up with new installs.

Comment: It updated some packages but still giving the same error

Comment: @sourabhghorpade Did it show any vulnerabilities issues? if so, have you used `npm audit fix --force` ?

Comment: it showed like 136 vulnerabilities by using however i used --force,still only got fixed and it is showing 134 still require manual review and error is still there

Comment: @sourabhghorpade right, you have a messed up package.json which has many version mismatches. Please try to re-create the project with the fresh latest ionic version. delete your `node_modules` folder and run `npm cache clean` and then re-create the whole project. and also check you are using latest npm.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was an error with App-scripts in ionic module.i changed it with => https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts.git this app-script and it worked Thanks though. ;)

Comment: Did you remove the npm installed module of ionic-app-script and replace with the mentioned link files?